# Can CPU die if it is not used long?

Tags: cpu

simple question, but I can't find a single person who asked it in any forum
can a CPU die if not being used like an SSD or HDD?
we are talking for 40 years or more
I don't really think something should happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CPU is an integrated circuit (so also is an SSD and a memory stick). These devices do not die from not being used.

People start up old computers and (assuming the hard drive starts) they will run.

I have picked up surplus electronic gear with integrated circuits in them and they almost always work properly.

Resistors, capacitors (excluding some electrolytic capacitors), integrated circuits, diodes, transistors and such do not die from not being used.

Comment: While this is absolutely correct, there are some cases when the circuits are stored in bad environments, e.g. with high humidity, when water accumulates inside them, and you switch the power on, they get damaged and it seems that they are dead, but in reality they just died moments ago. I think this is worth noticing.

Comment: While harsh environments can damage parts (true as you say), in most environments, parts as I mentioned are fine. I have a couple of old instruments in my workshop (one from mid-60's with tubes and one from the late 70's all solid state) that hum along just fine. I keep them dry and cool.